# What is the best way to store local in android?

Tags: android

I have to build a quiz app with 1500 questions .I only need one random question . so i don't really have to load all the questions once ..
What is the best way to store those questions sql,json,xml ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably with that amount of questions, I'd go by using a SQL database. It depends, however, what kind of choose, if local or a centralized one.

If you plan to change the questions from time to time, you can have a relatively strong server where the users might connect to a webservice and get the questions, I'd recommend a centralized storage database.

If you plan to not change them, they'll be static, or the same for all users, or you can't simply afford having a remote server, use a `SQLite` database which is local to every device, and each time you start your app, simply load the questions (or do queries when you need to get them).

Answer (score 1):

In my oppinion, the best way in your case is to save all data on server, and when it nessery - create Post request to server and get data from it. If you want to store your data on phone, and use this data offline - SQLite is the best solution, about it you can read in [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
great tutorial